# Loading files onto EC2

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to get started with EC2 running a django site on a micro-linux installation (ie trying to take advantage of the AWS free tier to work out my horrible newbie mistakes).  I've installed the [bitnami AMI](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack%20Bitnami%20AMI) and it seems to work. Now I'm wondering what is the easiest way to get my django app files from my computer to EBS for my EC2 instance to access? I read some stuff about making a repository and accessing it with an SCM from within the instance, but that looks pretty complicated for what I think should be a simple thing.  Is there some way I could transfer all the data (in the correct folder structure) into my S3 bucket and from there into the EBS volume?
Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Use secure ssh and scp. Or put a tarball in S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Spike. In the end I used WinSCP and it was very simple.

Comment: Guide for connecting with WinSCP is here: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2